# Passing Mysql data to PHP array then to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, numeric

Let me start by explaining the situation:

I have a MySql table that contains several columns, of which a user id, a race id, a lap time, a lap number and I want to put this information into an array in PHP which I will then send to a java script.

My JavaScript array should end up looking like this :

first row:

> `[laptime1 user1, laptime2 user1, laptime3 user1,...]`

second row:

> `[laptime1 user2, laptime2 user2, laptime3 user2,...]`

Here's my current situation:

I first tried to test this situation for a single user and ran into lots of problems because my lap times in MySql are floats and when using json_encode it turned everything into strings, which did not work for my javascript as it started outputting the wrong values.
For example:
The first value was "8" instead of "84,521", then the second value was "4", etc..)...

Sadly, I found a potential solution with the numeric check option, but cannot use it as my hosting runs a PHP version that doesn't support it.

So I found the following solution, which I fiddled with a bit and that works for a single user (it might look messy to you, I'm really a beginner and punching above my weight, but it works) :

```
$query = doquery("SELECT racelaptime,userid FROM {{table}} WHERE raceid='1' ORDER BY racelap", "liverace");
while(($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))) {
    $data[] = (float)$result['racelaptime'];
}

$script = $script . "\nvar myArray = new Array(";
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    if ($key < (count($data)-1)){
        $script = $script . $value . ',';
    }
    else {
        $script = $script . $value . ");\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs an array in JavaScript that looks like this :

```
myArray=[84.521,83.800,81.900]
```

Which is great, as this is exactly what my java script requires as input (time in seconds, separated by commas for each lap).

Now I would like to implement the multiple user element but I'm stumped as to how I can work that out...

My MySQL query is still sorted by race lap but I also kind of need to sort the data by user id as I want all the laps of each user sorted in 1 row, Also, the user id is unknown to me and can vary (depends which user posts the time) so I can't really do a "if userid==1 save this here and then go to next one".

Should I use a foreach statement in the while loop that stores the data, but how can I tell him to store all the laps by the same user in the first row (and the next user in the second row, etc...) without using tons of SQL queries ?

If you can offer a more elegant solution than my current one for passing the PHP array to JavaScript, I would be more than happy to make changes but otherwise a simple solution using the current "setup" would be great too (hope it's all clear enough).

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: share your $data output and desire java script array format..

Comment: The desired JavaScript array format I have above is okay, however I simply wanted to have each row contain another user's lap times (same format though), that way I can parse through it in my script using myArray[lap number][user]. My problem was more on the php side, my $data is an array that simply contains the same times as the myArray example above (but in php).

Comment: if you are getting simple php array data then you should use '$jArray = implode (',', $data)'. it will concat your array data with comma separated like (11221.45, 1212.66, 21212.66) and then later you convert it in java script like <script>var jsArray = new Array ('<?php echo $jArray; ?>');</script>. let me know if it's not working.

Comment: Will that take into account several rows though ?
As in, will it concat each values per row together separated by commas or will it mesh it all within one row ?

Comment: yes, because you are storing only one column from each array data. it would be nice if you share your array data with print_r. or you can use group_concat and group by clause in your query statement. like, "SELECT user_id, group_concat( laptime ) AS laptime
FROM `speed`
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id
LIMIT 0 , 30"

Comment: This is the output for the data Array before changing anything: Array ( [0] => 84.510 [1] => 84.970 [2] => 25.000 [3] => 66.000 [4] => 12.000 )
0,2,3 and 4 are posted by userid 1 and 1 is posted by userid 2.
That's why I would like it to put that different data set in another row.

I did test Foxhound's solution below which seems to work as the output, when modified with a multidimensional array shows for $data:

Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 84.510 [1] => 25.000 [2] => 66.000 [3] => 12.000 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 84.970 ) )

However I now don't know how to move that over to my java script.

Comment: I've tried to use json_encode on the $data array and it gives me :
{"1":["84.510","25.000","66.000","12.000"],"2":["84.970"]}
But I just can't seem to make it usable in java...
If I try to view it using alert('$data[value]') it considers the whole thing a string and just outputs the unique characters (i.e for 1 it spits out ").

Comment: you can use php var in java script like this var data = <?php echo $json ;?>;
for(var key in data) {
    alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + data[key]);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple user element I would use a multidimensional array >

```
$query = doquery("SELECT racelaptime,userid FROM {{table}} WHERE raceid='1' ORDER BY racelap", "liverace");

// Loop the DB result
while(($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))) {

    // Check if this ID is already in the data array
    if(!array_key_exists($result['userid'], $data)){

        // Create array for current user
        $data[$result['userid']] = array();

    }

    // Add the current race time to the array (do not need to use the float)
    $data[$result['userid']][] = $result['racelaptime'];

}

// Echo json data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now what you need to do on the Javascript side when handling this array is to go through each of the user

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){

       // Use parseFloat to keep the decimal value
       alert(key + ' Has the following values - ' + value);

       // If you want to display the racing values you simply
       $.each(value, function(k, parseFloat(v)){

             alert(v);

       })

 })
```

Is this what you needed or am I completely out of the scope?

Comment: The "check if this ID exists" is actually a great solution for my first problem, this way I should have a proper array and sorted per user and per lap as I wanted it, thanks I hadn't thought of that !
The Javascript part I'm not entirely sure yet, I will try and implement your suggestion, see how it's being output and come back to confirm.